# How to display in Android the Payment Methods the user have in Braintree vaults?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, braintree

I'm using Braintree as payment gateway. I have created a custom UI for allow the user checkout and also a custom UI to display the payment methods the user have saved in Braintree vaults.
 I have two view point in this problem. First, I have created an endpoint in my server for return the payment methods. Then I show those payment methods in my Android app. The problem is I need to know HOW to create a payment method nonce from the payment methods the user select using the payment method token.

The second view point: What is the best way to show in a Custom UI the payment methods to the user, and allow to the user pay with a saved payment method?????

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Hi, Charlie can we suggest me for the same problem i have faced

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact support.

Instead of using a `payment_method_nonce` for transactions, you can pass in the [`token`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method/node#token) for the [`PaymentMethod`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method/node) you wish to transact with. You can save the `token` associated with each `PaymentMethod` and when the user selects a `PaymentMethod` and submits, you can send the token to your server to complete the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer. You can create an Transaction in Braintree with the payment method token or with the payment method nonce.